# Core data transient values with Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

Does anyone know, or have an example of, how to handle core data transient values with Swift?  I know to use @NSManaged before the properties, but can't figure out how to code the logic to build the transient values using Swift.

Comment: Having @NSManaged does not allow me to create a getter for the transient property in Swift.  I would like to know how transient property works in Swift as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoreData Swift and transient attribute getters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960555/coredata-swift-and-transient-attribute-getters)

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? Did the given link help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check mark the **transient** field in your data model for particular attribute(e.g. `sectionTitle`).
Create class for that entity, it will look something like

```
 class Message: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var body: String?
    @NSManaged var time: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var sectionTitle: String?
}
```

Edit it and make it like this:

```
class Message: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var body: String?
    @NSManaged var time: NSDate?

    var sectionTitle: String? {
        return time!.getTimeStrWithDayPrecision()
        //'getTimeStrWithDayPrecision' will convert timestamp to day
        //just for e.g.
        //you can do anything here as computational properties
    }
}
```

---

**Update- Swift4**
Use `@objc` tag for Swift 4 as:

```
@objc var sectionTitle: String? {
   return time!.getTimeStrWithDayPrecision()
}
```

Comment: This works good if "Codegen" in Entity property is set to "manual/none". How to handle it "Codegen" is set to "Category/Extension"?

Comment: With swift 4 I had to use "@objc dynamic var sectionTitle: String? {...}" in a similar case to make it work.

Comment: The transient property will not work for sort descriptors when used in fetch request. It will give an error as keypath yourTransientVariable not found in entity <NSSQLEntity EntityName id=1> with userInfo of (null). you can only filter and sort on non-transient attributes.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17853561/2545465

Answer (score 1):

We should use willAccessValueForKey and didAccessValueForKey to support KVO