# Can nsfetchedresultscontroller section names be observed for changes?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `NSFetchedResultsController` with section names that may change without any actual changes to the `NSFetchedResultsController`s' fetch request entity.

Is there a way to observe changes to the `sectionnamekeypath` so that a `UITableView` section name will update when one of the names of the `NSFetchedResultsController`s' sections is updated?

EDIT:
I use the transient property `listNameSectionHeader`, below, as the `sectionNameKeyPath`. When a `list.name` changes, the section header for that `list.name` does not change accordingly, and I am not sure why.

```
- (NSString*)listNameSectionHeader {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"listNameSectionHeader"];
    NSString *listNameSectionHeader = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"listNameSectionHeader"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"listNameSectionHeader"];
    if (listNameSectionHeader == nil) {
        listNameSectionHeader = [self recalculateListNameSectionHeader];
    }
    return listNameSectionHeader;
}
- (NSString*)recalculateListNameSectionHeader {

    __ENTERING_METHOD__
    NSString *listNameSectionHeader = self.list.name;
    [self setListNameSectionHeader:listNameSectionHeader];
    return listNameSectionHeader;
}
```

Comment: Are you storing section names outside the fetch request entity? If so, try to save it in fetch request entity OR else make it computational(transient) depending on saved property.

Comment: I made the sectionNameKeyPath a transient property (based on another entity's attribute), but when the transient property changes, the section header does not refresh. I thought it should - I am so confused.

Comment: How are making it transient? plz check this answer [stack link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729190/core-data-transient-values-with-swift/36162207#36162207)