# NSManagedObject custom getter not working for NSSortDescriptor

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nssortdescriptor

I have an `NSManagedObject` that I am overriding the getter for one of the properties because I want to do some calculations for the return value of that property:

```
- (NSNumber *)distanceFromCurrentUserLocation {

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"distanceFromCurrentUserLocation"];

    // Update Distance
    CLLocation *placeLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.coordinate.latitude longitude:self.coordinate.longitude];
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [[MyHelper sharedService] currentLocation];

    CLLocationDistance distance = [placeLocation distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];

    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"distanceFromCurrentUserLocation"];

    return @(distance);

}
```

I then do a fetch request and set my `sortDescriptors`:

```
// Initialize Fetch Request
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"ZSSCDPerson"];

// Sorting
[request setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distanceFromCurrentUserLocation" ascending:ascending]]];
```

**Do sort descriptors not call this method?**

Comment: Is this helpful?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853496/nssortdescriptor-on-transient-attribute-for-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: SQLite database store type? No, the fetch request is translated to SQL and the `NSManagedObject` subclasses aren't used.

Comment: Yes, SQLite database store type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort a fetch request on a non-stored value.

You have two options.

1. Calculate and store the value, you need to update this anytime the current user location changes. Might not be ideal for something that changes a lot like user location though.
2. Fetch then sort. Fetch all your objects into an array then sort in memory.

Comment: I have tried to avoid fetching then sorting. Reason being it takes longer to update a private context then merge with the main thread context.

Comment: You could try fetching a subset of your data (ie just the location info) to find the required order then do the complete fetch using that info.

Comment: Do you mean just fetch the attributes that I need for the calculation? I would still need to loop through those results to do the location distance calculation on each result.

Comment: Yes you still need to do the calc of course, it has to be done somewhere.